# angular2 select option from select list

Tags: angular

I want to show default option 'All' from my option lists and its not working.

> > filter.component.ts

```
@Output() onFilter = new EventEmitter<String>();

statusOptions = [
 { value: 'active', viewValue: 'Active' },
 { value: 'inactive', viewValue: 'Inactive' },
 { value: 'pending', viewValue: 'Pending' }
 ];

onStatusChange(val) {
  if (val === "") {
   this.onFilter.emit("");
 }
  else {
    this.onFilter.emit(`?status=${val}`);
  }
 }
```

> > filter.component.html

```
<form class="filter-form">
  <md-select (ngModelChange)="onStatusChange($event)" name="filter">
    <md-option [value]="" selected="selected">All</md-option>
    <md-option [value]="status.value" *ngFor="let status of statusOptions">
      {{status.viewValue}}
    </md-option>
  </md-select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `[ngModel]="selected"` instead of `selected="selected"`

```
<md-select [ngModel]="selected" (ngModelChange)="onStatusChange($event)" name="filter">
```

where the components field `selected` references the selected value from `statusOptions`.

Comment: it didnt work , used your code above instead of selected="selected"

Comment: What did you assign to `selected`? I guess you need `selected:any = '';` because the element you want to be initially selected is not created by `*ngFor` and has value ``.  Actually it should be `value=""` or `[value]="''"` or alternatively `selected:any; // without = '';` (to initialize to `null`)

Comment: <md-select (ngmodel) = "selected" (ngModelChange)="onStatusChange($event)" name="filter">

     <md-option [value]="''" selected = "selected:any =''">All</md-option>

>> you mean like this?

Comment: This part `selected = "selected:any =''"` is redundant in the template. This code was meant to be added to the components class.

Comment: kept `selected = "selected:any =''"` in component.ts file but still not selecting default 'All' option

Comment: Why did you keep it? As I said, it's redundant.

Comment: oh sorry, I am abit new to this. I have removed now but it is still not working
can you provide me the codes pls?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do. You need a field `selected` in your components class (when the binding is [ngModel]="selected"`)  and its value needs to match the value of `<md-option [value]="..."`. If they match, then `<md-select` will show that option as selected.

Comment: You need a field `selected`  in your components class.
>> you mean in `filter-component.ts` isnt it?

Comment: Yes, that's what I try to explain ;-)

Comment: actually when i said kept `selected: any =''` in component.ts above i kept that in `filter-component.ts` and it doesnt work

Comment: Use it with  `<md-option value="" selected="selected">All</md-option>`

Comment: is it working on your machine? its not working on mine

Comment: Sorry, forgot to remove `selected="selected"` in my last comment when I copied the code line from your question. It should be ` 
Use it with <md-option value="">All</md-option>`. If it doesn't work add your **current** code to your question.

Comment: Yeah, this code should work. Reading the comments, I see that you have mistakenly used `(ngModel)` instead of what Günther suggested -> `[ngModel]` just remove `selected="selected"` from your options and use the code Günther suggested :)

Comment: yeah i have tried using `[ngModel]` but it show error like `Can't bind to 'ngmodel' since it isn't a known property of 'md-select'.`
 i have imported form module and material module in my module.ts file

Comment: If the error message is `Can't bind to 'ngmodel' since it ` you haven't use `[ngModel]` but `[ngmodel]`

Comment: filter.component.ts

`statusOptions = [
    { value: 'active', viewValue: 'Active' },
    { value: 'inactive', viewValue: 'Inactive' },
    { value: 'pending', viewValue: 'Pending' }
  ];

  selected = "selected:any = ''";`





filter.component.html
`<md-select [ngModel] = "selected" (ngModelChange)="onStatusChange($event)" name="filter">
        <md-option [value]="">All</md-option> 
</md-select>

>> you mean like this right? 
`

Comment: It should be `<md-option value=""`

Comment: Try to reproduce in a Plunker, then I can have another look.